# My package installed with pip install shows no modules

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have a simple Python project with effectively one package (called `forcelib`) containing one module (also called `forcelib`):

```
- setup.py
- forcelib
  |- __init__.py
  |- forcelib.py
```

My `setup.py` is copied from the [official example](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py) and has the obvious edits.

The problem is that I can install the `forcelib` package using `pip` but when I import `forcelib`, it only has the "double-underscore" attributes visible.  That is, I cannot see the `forcelib` module.

Example to replicate:

1. `git clone https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib`
2. `cd forcelib`
3. `pip install -e .`
4. `python`
5. `import forcelib`
6. `print(forcelib.__version__)`  # Correctly prints 0.1.2
7. `dir(forcelib)`  # The only contents are the `__version__`, `__path__` etc. double-underscore attributes.  I had expected to see `forcelib`, `example_read` etc.

Perhaps I'm supposed to [distribute just the module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-module) rather than bother with a package.

The (very small) [project is on GitHub](https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you looking for the modules/package contents?

Comment: `import forcelib; dir(forcelib)`.  There's nothing there except the double-underscore attributes

Comment: by importing `forcelib` you are importing forcelib's `__init__`. try `from forcelib import forcelib; dir(forcelib)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are 2 ways of doing it:

1. Keep the same directory structure but put the following in `__init__.py`

   from .forcelib import *
2. Distribute a module, not a package.  Follow [the instructions to use the py_modules](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-module) argument rather than the `packages` argument in `setup.py`.  This would mean restructuring the project to:

   - setup.py
   - forcelib.py

Approach (1) [can be seen here](https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib/tree/f7fc9f9378ba5caa1b971900ed09a364f4cd565d).  It has the advantage of hiding the private functions and attributes (anything not in `__all__`), but the client can still see the module `forcelib.forcelib`, which I don't think it should.

Approach (2) [can be seen here](https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib/tree/6ff9e82a13107876773b6cd3986c01286da887e4).  It is simpler, but has the disadvantage that it does not hide private functions and attributes.

Answer (score -1):

**Download zip file and extract zip after go to forcelib-master directory
then open command prompt and go to forcelib-master directory in command prompt and run command**

```
python setup.py install
```

[image]

It will install packages successfully